# the sum of $f_0+f_2+f_4+f_6+\cdots+f_{2n}$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I really feel like I am missing something.
Geometricly, this sum is clear:
[image]
it's $f_{2n+1}-1$
$$\require{cancel}$$

But when I use the identity $f_{2n}=f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^2$ I get the following
$$0+(f_2^2-f_0^2)+(f_3^2-f_1^2)+(f_4^2-f_2^2)+\cdots+(f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^2)=$$
$$=0+(\cancel{f_2^2}-f_0^2)+(\cancel{f_3^2}-f_1^2)+(\cancel{f_4^2}-\cancel{f_2^2})+\cdots+(f_{n+1}^2-\cancel{f_{n-1}^2})=$$
$$=f_{n+1}^2-1$$
$$\therefore f_{n+1}^2-1=f_{2n+1}-1$$
$$f_{n+1}^2=f_{2n+1}$$
I can also use $f_{2n+1}=f_{n+1}^2+f_n^2$:
$$f_{n+1}^2=f_{n+1}^2+f_n^2$$
$$\Rightarrow0=f_n^2$$
Which is clearly wrong. Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve canceled the terms incorrectly I think. The last 2 terms will be 
$$(f_n^2\ -\ f_{n-2}^2)\ +\ (f_{n+1}^2\ -\ f_{n-1}^2)$$
Out of which,
$$ f_n^2 \ and\ f_{n+1}^2 $$
won’t cancel out. Thus eventually you’ll get $0=0$